# Openness of static iOS library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I wonder how to block to preview static's library .m files while i'm profiling app by Instruments like Time Profiler.
All of methods are open to view.

Answer (score 2):

The symbols are visible yes, but the linker needs to see those in order to use your library.  In other words, you can hide the symbols, but it would render the library useless.

However the implementation is not visible and needs serious technology to reverse-engineer back into source form (I am not aware of a product that can do it, however I haven't looked for one).